# How select row of space 1 byte in datatable?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I has a Datatable and find as my code:

```
Dim strChar=" "; '///Unicode =0020-space 1 bytes (or Unicode =3000 -space 2 bytes)
Dim orow = dt.Select(String.Format("char_string='{0}'", strChar.Replace("'", "''")))
```

Result of : `orow` is a row has `char_string="〇"  '//Unicode=3007`

Why `Select` work not correct?

Comment: Values of 3000 and 3007 don't fit into 1 byte.

Comment: i try with unicode =0020 , result still char_string="〇"